# How to create ZStream of String from ZStream of Byte

Tags: zio, sttp, zio-streams

I need to read file from http. I'm using sttp with ZioBackend like this:

```scala
val sttpBackend: SttpBackend[Task, ZioStreams] = ???

val request =
  basicRequest
    .post(uri"...")
    .response(asStreamUnsafe(ZioStreams))
    .readTimeout(Duration.Inf)

val response: ZIO[
  Any, 
  Throwable, 
  Response[Either[String, Stream[Throwable, Byte]]]
] = sttpBackend.send(request)
```

How to go from `Stream[Throwable, Byte]` to `Stream[Throwable, String]` in which each string would be a line from response body?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to go is to use `ZTransducer` in zio1.x:

```scala
  def decodeLines: ZTransducer[Any, Nothing, Byte, String] =
    ZTransducer.utf8Decode >>> ZTransducer.splitLines

  stream.transduce(decodeLines)
```

Or in zio2.x via `ZPipeline`:

```scala
stream.via(ZPipeline.utf8Decode >>> ZPipeline.splitLines)
```